# JQgrid: data display strange

Tags: css, jqgrid

I got this trouble after try to attach the table into html page:
[image]
and the page have css style :

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300">
<link href="development-bundle/themes/redmond/jquery.ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<link href="development-bundle/themes/redmond/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<link href="development-bundle/themes/redmond/jquery.ui.tabs.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<link href="development-bundle/themes/redmond/jquery.ui.dialog.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<link href="development-bundle/themes/redmond/jquery.ui.datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="jqGrid/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="jqGrid/plugins/ui.multiselect.css" />
    <script src="jqGrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jqGrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.tabs.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery-validate/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    #container{ height: 700px;}
    #center_container{ 
                      background:#DDD;
                      height:700px;
                      width: 1100px;
                      margin: 0 auto;
                      }
    .ui-widget {font-size: 14px;}
    .ui-widget-content{float:left; width:1030px; margin-left:35px;background:#CEF6F5;}
    .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel {padding:1em 0em; width:700px; margin: 10px 10px;}
    .ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td {
                             white-space: normal !important;
                             font-size:0.8em;
                             height: auto;
                             }
    .ui-jqgrid-titlebar {font-size:2em; color: yellow;}
    .ui-state-highlight { background: yellow !important; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at this one :

```
.ui-widget-content{float:left; width:1030px; margin-left:35px;background:#CEF6F5;}
```

delete this part :

```
.ui-widget-content{/*float:left;*/ width:1030px; /*margin:20px auto;*/background:#CEF6F5;}
 div#gbox_list{margin-left:15px;}
```